# pivot pandas dataframe while having multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am have a dataframe as shown below:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'name':['bil','bil','bil','bil','jim', 'jim', 
'jim', 'jim'],'col2': ['acct1','law', 'acct1','law', 'acct1','law', 
'acct1','law'],'col3': ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
})

     col2 col3 name
0  acct1    a  bil
1    law    b  bil
2  acct1    c  bil
3    law    d  bil
4  acct1    e  jim
5    law    f  jim
6  acct1    g  jim
7    law    h  jim
```

I have tried convering it into below format using but not sure how to proceed after this:

```
d = d.groupby(['name', 'col2'])['col3'].apply(lambda x: 
x.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index()

   name   col2  0  1
0  bil  acct1  a  c
1  bil    law  b  d
2  jim  acct1  e  g
3  jim    law  f  h
```

My expected format is as show below:

```
    acc1 law name
 0    a   b  bil
 1    c   d  bil
 2    e   f  jim
 3    g   h  jim
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter `Series`, create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then reshape by second level (`col2`) by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and `1`, because python count from `0`:

```
g = d.groupby(['name', 'col2'])['col3'].cumcount()

d = (d.set_index(['name', 'col2', g])['col3']
     .unstack(1)
     .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
     .reset_index()
     .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (d)
  name acct1 law
0  bil     a   b
1  bil     c   d
2  jim     e   f
3  jim     g   h
```

Comment: Works like a  charm. Thanks for the solution!!